# What is a Re-Tileable Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it a ***Re-Tileable Word™***.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

| Re-tileable Word™ | Non-re-tileable Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| KALE | CHARD |
| ROOSTER | COCKEREL |
| KARMA | FORTUNE |
| SALMON | MACKEREL |
| TEST | QUIZ |
| DREAM | NIGHTMARE |
| FAST | QUICK |
| CRAFT | ORIGAMI |
| VIEW | SCENERY |
| ORGAN | GLAND |
| SCORE | MARKS |
| EROTIC | SEXUAL |

Here is a CSV version:

```
Re-tileable Word™, Non-re-tileable Word™  

KALE, CHARD  
ROOSTER, COCKEREL  
KARMA, FORTUNE   
SALMON, MACKEREL  
TEST, QUIZ  
DREAM, NIGHTMARE  
FAST, QUICK  
CRAFT, ORIGAMI  
VIEW, SCENERY  
ORGAN, GLAND  
SCORE, MARKS  
EROTIC, SEXUAL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Re-Tileable Word™ seems to be ...

> ... an [allowable Scrable word](http://scrabblewordfinder.org/check) that can be anagrammed to one or more other allowable Scrabble words. Some anagrams are obscure e.g. makar, monals, tercio, but they are all in the Scrabble dictionary. The Un-Re-Tileable words have no useful anagrams.

These words are Re-Tileable™, because ...

> ... to make an anagram of a word on a Scrabble board just means to rearrange the tiles.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, except that I used this random http://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html anagram solver which did not give anything useful for `KARMA`. Then I dropped the idea.

Comment: @Matsmath: I've used [the Word Wizard](http://www.chambers.co.uk/word-wizard.php) from the Chambers website. It can find only single words and some fixed expressions, but it tells you whether a word is a valid Scrabble word. (And it can find words that aren't even in Chambers.)