# What is a Confused Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Confused Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| CONFUSED WORD™ | NOT CONFUSED WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| READER | WRITER |
| FRIEND | ENEMY |
| SHELF | FLOOR |
| WEATHER | FORECAST |
| LAME | GRACEFUL |
| LICENSED | BANNED |
| TEACHING | LEARNING |
| CHEATERS | HONESTY |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
CONFUSED WORD™, NOT CONFUSED WORD™
READER,WRITER
FRIEND,ENEMY
SHELF,FLOOR
WEATHER,FORECAST
LAME,GRACEFUL
LICENSED,BANNED
TEACHING,LEARNING
CHEATERS,HONESTY
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Re-Tileable Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/what-is-a-re-tileable-word)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obvious guess is:

> a Confused Word is a word which is an anagram of another word.

Confused Words:

> READER ~ DEARER
>  FRIEND ~ FINDER
>  SHELF ~ FLESH
>  WEATHER ~ WHEREAT
>  LAME ~ MEAL
>  LICENSED ~ DECLINES
>  TEACHING ~ CHEATING
>  CHEATERS ~ TEACHERS

Whereas the words in the second column

> don't appear to be anagrams of other words.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic here, but how about Enemy -> Yemen?

Comment: @Matsmath I'm assuming proper nouns don't count - I believe they're not allowable in Scrabble, for example.

Comment: Well that was quick. Thought it might be a bit too easy :) I'll accept the answer once I'm able.

Comment: I'm guessing it also doesn't take dated forms (rewrit)

Comment: How are these different from [Re-Tileable words](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/what-is-a-re-tileable-word/42815#42815) then, expect maybe the looser stance on what exactly is a valid word?

Comment: @MOehm Good question. Maybe we should VTC the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a Confused Word™ is one that:

> Can be an anagram of another word

In the list:

> REREAD, FINDER, FLESH, WREATHE, MALE, SILENCED, CHEATING, TEACHERS